# Python service uses 100% of CPU on while loop with sleep (inside docker container)

Tags: python, docker, asynchronous, async-await, sleep

I have a python3 code that does something like this:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def main():
    while True:
        if should_end():
            break
        # time.sleep(0.5)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I've tested it with `time.sleep(0.5)` and `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` but for both cases it is using 100% of CPU.

```sh
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
f698d943d5d5        my-container      100.66%                 5.7MiB / 15.52GiB   0.16%               0B / 0B             56.9MB / 0B         30
```

I'm running the docker container in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not reproducible on my machine - docker stats shows 0.12%. 1. What is the CPU usage if you launch it without docker? 2. What does `should_end` do?

Comment: `top` says 24% but that is because the machine has 4 processors.

Comment: I think top displays cpu% for one core by default: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command. Have you tried profiling the code? (Without profiler output, i have only silly ideas like wrong indentation of sleep or should_end spinning and using the cpu)

Comment: @Lesiak I'm going to provide a better example, it is really bothering me.